# Broadcast a message to all connected users via Phabricator notification server

Tags: push-notification, notifications, broadcast, phabricator

Phabricator supports desktop notifications when a page you are viewing is updated. Is there an easy way to utilize this functionality to broadcast a message to all connected clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be having all your users subscribing a project and then the changes to the project will be broadcast to all the users subscribing it. There are two problems here:

- you should have some kind of plugin in Phabricator to have all your users subscribed to this project.
- you should lock the users from unsubscribing this project.

Comment: Hey that's a good idea! Thanks, I think I can implement that pretty easily.